# "Add as link" in Netbeans?

Tags: php, netbeans, netbeans-7

How can I (in the Netbeans IDE) add files as links, or point to existing files, kind of like a shortcut?

Visual Studio 2012 can do this, as shown in the following screenshot (found on Google Images - not mine).

[image]

I miss this feature in Netbeans. Copying my files over all the time is not an option, since I constantly improve my PHP library files, that are used across all other projects.

I am using the full version of Netbeans, and in this case, I am doing PHP development.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that PHP is supposed to work like that, since its code is not compiled.
I could be completely wrong, and if I am, I'm sure someone else will educate us both.

What I've usually done is put the library in some directory and then add that directory to PHP's include path by adding this to php.ini:

```
include_path = "dir to your library"
```

And then I'd make sure that whatever class autoloader I was using was looking through the include path.

That said, I've more recently moved away from this, because a global library that changes often has caused me problems (a change would break something and similar issues).

Comment: What I want it to do is that it should take the original files when I publish them to FTP, and then take those with them.